# Dataframe-like operations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pandas, dataframe

I love the Spark dataframe API in Python or Scala, or Pandas in Python to express typical data manipulations like filtering, select, simple joins, etc.

For a little project I realised that doing that server side with Spark is huge overkill, doing it in Python server side is also an overkill and this could all be done nicely in Javascript, directly in the Angular2 application.

I image building an Angular "data manipulation" `service` for that part of the app, that service would delegate the data querying to another service doing a REST call.

The question is: I could not find a JS library for that purpose, should I try to build it myself or could someone provide more information or suggest using a different technique?

Comment: I fear the off-topic, if so on which SE could I ask the question? Thanks

Comment: You could explore underscore.js or lodash.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try Data-Forge: A data manipulation toolkit for JavaScript inspired by Pandas and LINQ.

Here's an example transforming a CSV file:

```
dataForge.readFileSync('input.csv')     // Read input file.
    .parseCSV()                         // Parse CSV data to a dataframe. 
    .parseInts("Column2", "Column3")    // Parse from strings to integers.
    .parseDates("Column4")              // Parse from strings to date objects.
    .dropSeries("Column5")              // Don't want column 5.
    .where(row => predicate(row))       // Filter out rows that you don't want.
    .select(row => transform(row))      // Apply transformation to each row.
    .asCSV()                            // Write out data file in CSV (or other) format.
    .writeFileSync('output.csv');       // Write output file.
```

http://www.data-forge-js.com/